# Function jQuery doesn't works in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not understand why this basic function does not work correctly in these browsers, when I typing in the browser console the message is 'undefined'.

```
    function fillYears(year) {
         var yearToSet = year - 7;
         $('#SelectYear a').each(function () {
             this.text = yearToSet;
             yearToSet++;
         });
     }
```

Sorry if it's something simple and I do not notice.
Thank you very much.

Comment: try `$(this).text(yearToSet);`

Comment: what is undefined? BTW, are you suggesting this code works on Firefox?!

Comment: only undefined or  `fillYears is undefined`

Comment: the problem is that <a> are not filled correctly

Comment: `<a> are not filled completely` so what, they are filled partially or what? PLEASE, improve your question, it is completly unclear what you are asking...

Comment: there is no `text` in DOM.

Comment: @Nacho, Make sure you look at my answer. The `each` loop is not necessary to achieve what you want and I also simplified your initial function.

Comment: @ plalx yes I read your response, I doing testing, thank you very much! (sorry for my english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
function fillYears(year) {
     var yearToSet = year - 7;

     $('#SelectYear a').each(function () {
         $(this).text(yearToSet++);
     });
}
```

Or simply:

```
function fillYears(year) {
     var yearToSet = year - 7;

     $('#SelectYear a').text(function () {
         return yearToSet++;
     });
}
```

And if you want to debug your code, `console.log` is not the most appropriate way. In most browsers you can put a `debugger;` statement anywhere in your code to set a breakpoint at that location.

Answer (score 3):

You're not returning anything, therefore the function returns 'undefined'.

Try

```
function fillYears(year) {
         var yearToSet = year - 7;
         $('#SelectYear a').each(function () {
             this.text = yearToSet;
             yearToSet++;
         });
         return yearToSet;
     }
//Also, call the function
```

and make sure there is an element on the page with an ID of `SelectYear` or there is an `a` tag.

PS:

The `a` tag has no property `text`.

Comment: That makes no sense. The name of the function doesn't suggest that it should return a value.

Comment: Ok, now not return 'undefined', but not fill the <a> with the numbers... Thans you

Comment: @plalx Exactly, but the OP is asking why the console outputs 'undefined'.  This makes the console 'output' `yearToSet`.  He obviously wants to see his values.

Comment: @Nacho Change `this.text = yearToSet` to `this.innerHTML = yearToSet`

Comment: with $ (this) does not work, not in firefox (the other way if it works in firefox)

Comment: @Nacho  Either use `this.text = yearToSet to this.innerHTML = yearToSet` or `$(this).text(yearToSet)`.  Also, please accept my answer if this helped ;)

Comment: @ Man of Snow Thanks! this works, thanks all for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ymuT7/20/

```
<a id="SelectYear" >1</a>
<a id="SelectYear" >2</a>
<a id="SelectYear" >3</a>

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {


    fillYears(2000);
});



function fillYears(year) {
         var yearToSet = year - 7;
         $("a[id='SelectYear']").each(function () {
             this.text = yearToSet;
             yearToSet++;
         });
     }
```